# How to force Sympy to substitute when using differentiation

Tags: sympy, substitution

I'd like to compute the second derivative of f(y(x)) using sympys diff:

```
diff(f(y(x)),x,2)
```

The result displayed is

```
Derivative(y(x), x)**2*Derivative(f(y(x)), y(x), y(x)) + Derivative(y(x), x, x)*Subs(Derivative(f(_xi_1), _xi_1), (_xi_1,), (y(x),))
```

[displayed equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKS0g.png)

How can I force the Subs to be carried out, i.e. How can I get the last part (=Subs...) to be transformed to $d^2/dy^2 f(y(x))$?

However, I'm also interested in the same question for higher derivatives.